# How does PROCINFO show info on FS on the specific record?

Tags: awk, gnu

I was reading the definition of the `PROCINFO` built-in variable on [GNU Awk User's Guide → 7.5.2 Built-in Variables That Convey Information](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Auto_002dset):

> PROCINFO #
>
> The elements of this array provide access to information about the running awk program. The following elements (listed alphabetically) are guaranteed to be available:
>
> ```
> PROCINFO["FS"]
> ```
>
> This is `"FS"` if field splitting with `FS` is in effect, `"FIELDWIDTHS"` if field splitting with `FIELDWIDTHS` is in effect, `"FPAT"` if field matching with `FPAT` is in effect, or `"API"` if field splitting is controlled by an API input parser.

And yes, it works very well. See this example when I provide the string "hello;you" and I set, by order, `FS` to ";", `FIELDWIDTHS` to "2 2 " and `FPAT` to three characters:

```sh
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=";"}{print PROCINFO["FS"]; print $1}' <<< "hello;you"
FS
hello
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="2 2 2"}{print PROCINFO["FS"]; print $1}' <<< "hello;you"
FIELDWIDTHS
he
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="..."}{print PROCINFO["FS"]; print $1}' <<< "hello;you"
FPAT
hel
```

This is fine and works very well.

The, a bit before they mention in [4.8 Checking How gawk Is Splitting Records](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Testing-field-creation):

> In order to tell which kind of field splitting is in effect, use `PROCINFO["FS"]` (see section [Built-in Variables That Convey Information](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Auto_002dset)). The value is `"FS"` if regular field splitting is being used, `"FIELDWIDTHS"` if fixed-width field splitting is being used, or `"FPAT"` if content-based field splitting is being used.

And also in [Changing FS Does Not Affect the Fields](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Full-Line-Fields) they describe how the changes affect the *next record*:

> According to the POSIX standard, awk is supposed to behave as if each record is split into fields at the time it is read. In particular, this means that if you change the value of `FS` after a record is read, the values of the fields (i.e., how they were split) should reflect the old value of `FS`, not the new one.

This case explains it very well:

```sh
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} {FS="|"; print $1}' <<< "hello;you
bye|everyone"
hello  # "hello;you" is splitted using FS=";", the assignment FS="|" doesn't affect it yet
bye    # "bye|everyone" is splitted using FS="|"
```

Having all of this into consideration, I would assume that `PROCINFO["FS"]` would always reflect the `"FS"` as the field splitting in the record it is being printed on.
However, see this case:

```sh
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="..."}{FS=";"; print PROCINFO["FS"]; print $1}' <<< "hello;you"
FS
hel
```

`PROCINFO["FS"]` shows the info set in the current record (FS), not the one that Awk is taking into account when processing the data (that is, FPAT). The same occurs if we swap the assignments:

```sh
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=";"}{FPAT="..."; print PROCINFO["FS"]; print $1}' <<< "hello;you"
FPAT
hello
```

Why is `PROCINFO["FS"]` showing a different FS than the one that is being used in the record it is printed in?

Comment: @luciole75w exactly! That is the correct behaviour and is described in the docs. However, PROCINFO does change immediately, which is inconsistent. It is what surprises me and the reason of the question (not sure if I expressed it clearly enough, feel free to edit it!)

Comment: sry, I read your post too quickly :/

Comment: When reading your question, I do think that the behaviour you present and the documentation you quote are in line. `PROCINFO["FS"]` returns the value which is in effect, i.e. the one that is going to be used, not the one that has been used.

Comment: @kvantour yes. But it sounds counterintuitive to me.

Comment: You want to be able to extract the information that has been used for the splitting. That would be also useful. But this information is in the end available if you make the **first** action read `{fs=PROCINFO["fs"]}` This will always be the value which is used to split the current record that is being processed. The same holds when you reassigne any field or record. If you do `{$1=$1; fs=PROCINFO["fs"]}` or `{$0="string"; fs=PROCINFO["fs"]}`, the string `fs` will always give you the value used for the splitting of the current active record `$0`. Obviously, it takes some more implementation.

Comment: A possible use-case can be found in the example program `passwd.awk` in https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Passwd-Functions

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' I think your confusion is in thinking that field splitting is something happens during processing of a record and so there's an FS value that applies during the time when the current record is being processed. That's not the case. Field splitting using the current value of FS happens when $0 is assigned a value. Period, full stop. You can change the value of FS 20 times during processing of the current record and it has no effect on field splitting but PROCINFO[FS] always simply reflects what FS (or FPAT or FIELDWIDTHS) is set to at that instant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field splitting (using FS, FIELDWIDTHS, or FPAT) occurs when a record is read or `$0` as a whole is given a new value otherwise (e.g. `$0="foo"` or `sub(/foo/,"bar")`). `print PROCINFO["FS"]` tells you the value that `PROCINFO["FS"]` **currently has** which is not necessarily the same value it had when field splitting last occurred.

With:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="..."}{FS=";"; print PROCINFO["FS"]; print $1}' <<< "hello;you"
FS
hel
```

You're setting `FS=";"` **after** `$1` has already been populated based on `FPAT="..."`, then printing `PROCINFO["FS"]` new value (which will be used the **next time** a record is split into fields), then printing the value of `$1` which was populated before you set `FS=";"`.

If you set `$0` to itself the field splitting will occur again, this time using the new FS value rather than the original FPAT value:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="..."}{FS=";"; print PROCINFO["FS"]; print $1; $0=$0; print $1}' <<< "hello;you"
FS
hel
hello
```